# how to fix the Apache2 Ubuntu Default Page in vagrant that uses ubuntu/trusty32

Tags: mysql, apache, ubuntu, vagrant

has anyone used ubuntu/trusty32 with vagrant on windows 7 environment with virtualbox, am new to vagrant and I installed it with all wat it needs i.e. apache2,php5,mysql and mysql workbench.when I run the server and access it in the browser I get the default **Apache2 Ubuntu Default Page** saying that I can edit the **index.html ** **(located at /var/www/html/index.html)** I have tried to look for this folder in windows bunt cant getit can anyone please help

Comment: The file should be in your virtualbox, not on your windows system. With `vagrant ssh` you can connect to your ubuntu and there you can edit this file. Vagrant also supports synced folders: http://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/getting-started/synced_folders.html

Comment: you mean I should check in the vagrant>.vagrant>machines>default or ?

Comment: Then you should try to connect to it like I mentioned it before. Search on youtube for "vagrant apache" or more general "vagrant tutorial", there are a lot of great tutorials out in the wild just waiting for you ;)

Comment: vagrant>.vagrant>machines>default sounds like your windows 7 filesystem, right? Then thats the wrong place to search. You run a virtual Ubuntu in your virtualbox, there your /var/www/html directory is located.

Comment: @PKeidel I installed the ubuntu/trusty32 using the git bash in vagrant .you are saying I should run the Vbox .am trying but no GUI or I should run it from the vagrant ssh terminal ?

Comment: There is no GUI when using vagrant. The only way is ssh.

Comment: VBoxManage startvm "Vagrant_default_1428163117681_34600" i have tried this command when am still in vagrant ssh but its giving me command not found

Comment: 1. Start your VM with `vagrant up` 2. connect via ssh with `vagrant ssh`

Comment: am in vagrant ssh now

Answer (score 1):

I worked around it : 
run

```
vagrant up
```

then

`vagrant ssh`

then

```
 cd /var/www/html
```

and lastly

```
ls
```

The **index.html** will be found there .to delete it run

```
sudo rm index.html
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Start your VM with `vagrant up`
2. connect via ssh with `vagrant ssh`
3. (Now you are in your ubuntu running in virtualbox)
4. Edit your files (/var/www/html/index.html)
5. Learn (maybe youtube tutorials) a lot more about VirtualBox, Linux, SSH, Commandline, vi or nano (commandline text editors)

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this issue by running this comment:

vagrant provision